# is it possible to show the status(config file loading path/log file path.etc) of service in macOS

Tags: macos, command-line, open-source

Now I am using this command to show status of nginx service in macOS:

```
brew services status nginx
```

show this error:

```
Error: Invalid usage: unknown subcommand: status
```

I want to know the nginx path and config file path but not fix homebrew or debug that. Are there alternate ways to check if the service is running and back trace to the files that control starting and stopping the web server process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search all service:

```
$ launchctl list |grep nginx                                                                                                                                                   ‹ruby-2.7.2›
-   1   homebrew.mxcl.nginx
```

list service:

```
    /usr/local/opt/nginx ⌚ 15:04:25
$ launchctl list homebrew.mxcl.nginx                                                                                                                                           ‹ruby-2.7.2›
{
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "Aqua";
    "Label" = "homebrew.mxcl.nginx";
    "OnDemand" = true;
    "LastExitStatus" = 256;
    "Program" = "/usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx";
    "ProgramArguments" = (
        "/usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx";
        "-g";
        "daemon off;";
    );
};
(base)
```